# Her with Mongoid, How to make a pluck?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Im using her to connect to my API, but i want to do a:

```
Vehicle.all.pluck :brand
```

where pluck is a Mongoid querying method. 
How do i achieve that with Her?

Comment: Vehicle.all.pluck(&:brand)

Comment: what means the & before the symbol?

Comment: @ViktorJusto: https://ruby-operators.herokuapp.com/#/pretzel